# Some function is ruining my json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a file named `test.json`. I need to load its contents into an array, make it possible to be edited and then put it back into a json string, so I can place it into a new file.

The problem is, that even if I load a file, convert it into an object, then into an array and eventually into a json string, it's not the same. It's losing some values. **Why?**

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest(); //load a file
request.open("GET", "levels/test.json", false);
request.send(null)
var mapTile = jQuery.parseJSON(request.responseText); //convert json to object

var array = $.map(mapTile, function(value, index) {
return value;
}); //convert object to array

// code to modify array [...]

var backToString = JSON.stringify(array); //convert array to json file
```

[image]

And here's original json file:

```
{ 
"1": {
  "1": { "type":"rock", "type2":"solid" },
  "2": { "type":"rock", "type2":"solid" },
  "3": { "type":"rock", "type2":"solid" },
  "4": { "type":"rock", "type2":"solid" } },
"2": {
  "1": { "type":"rock", "type2":"solid" },
  "2": { "type":"rock", "type2":"solid" },
  "3": { "type":"rock", "type2":"solid" },
  "4": { "type":"rock", "type2":"solid" } }
}
```

If you don't see the difference, an output string is missing leading `"1"` and `"2"`, making it unreadable.

I'm using the latest stable version of Chromium.

EDIT: I do realise `[` and `]` around the `backToString` variable. After clipping them, the problem still occurs.

Comment: The original object is: `{ "1": x, "2": y }`. You turn that into an array: `[ x, y ]`. Then you change the array. Then you turn the array back into an obj- whoops, no, you don't.

Comment: your'e converting an object to an array. of course it's not going to be the same.

Comment: @ChrisG I turn array back into a json string, not into an array. I never said I turn it back into an object, your sarcasm is not needed. `var backToString = JSON.stringify(array);`

Comment: @KajetanKrawczyk you said it's missing the leading "1" and "2". it's missing that because you made it an array. you threw the keys away when you converted it to an array (arrays are 0 indexed)

Comment: @KevinB How else can I do it?

Comment: don't convert it to an array maybe?

Comment: or maybe not store it as an object to begin with?

Comment: @KevinB I completly overlooked the fact I can still edit it while it's an object. That solves my problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First time you have an object, keys are 1 and 2.

After you have an array so the first key is 0 and second 1. You have no choice.

After you turn the JSON array in a String. Keys 0 and 1 are lost. That is just the representation of an array in JSON :

```
var t = [{name:"max"},{name:"john"}];
```

No key here ! That's normal

If you want to keep your keys you can try:

```
var k = 1;
var array = $.map(mapTile, function(value, index) {
var o = {};
o[k] = value;
k += 1;
return o;
}); //convert object to array
```

Comment: And **this** is an answer I was looking for. An explenation to my question "Why?". Thanks a lot.

Comment: I told you *why* in my very first comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn the array back into an object, otherwise you'll lose the keys.

```
var back = {};  // empty object
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    back[i + 1 + ""] = array[i];  // add array elements to it
}
var backToString = JSON.stringify(back); //convert array to json file
```